# Ignore meta characters in s3 file name

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-s3, amazon-aurora

I am trying to copy data from s3 to Aurora and using below comand to do that

```
aws_commons.create_s3_uri('mybucket','HourlyData/[20-10-2020]','us-east-1'),
aws_commons.create_aws_credentials('******', '***************', ''))
```

It woks fine for all the files except the files having square brackets([]) in the name.
for eg: HourlyData/[20-10-2020] file fails to load where as HourlyData/20-10-2020 gets loaded successfully

As I am getting the files from external source is there a way to fix this issue ?
I am getting below errors when loading files with [] in the name.

('ERROR', 'ERROR', 'XX000', 'HTTP 403. Permission denied. Check bucket or provided credentials as they may no longer be valid.', 'SQL function "table_import_from_s3" statement 1', 'aws_s3.c', '405', 'perform_import')

Answer (score 1):

Using those characters [is not recommended](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html)

Specifically these are the "safe" characters:

```
Forward slash (/)
Exclamation point (!)
Hyphen (-)
Underscore (_)
Period (.)
Asterisk (*)
Single quote (')
Open parenthesis (()
Close parenthesis ())
```

And the square brackets are specifically listed as "characters to avoid" in the documentation I linked.

The appropriate strategy, then, is probably to replace the square brackets before passing the filename. If you're going to need the s3 objects to stay correlated with the files afterward, you'd want to make a second function to reverse the first replacement.

For example:

```
def make_s3_safe_name(original_filename):
   return original_filename.replace('[', '(')).replace(']', ')')

def recover_original_name(s3_safe_name):
   return s3_safe_name.replace('(', ']')).replace(')', ']')

original_filename = 'HourlyData/[20-10-2020]'
s3_safe_filename = make_s3_safe_name(original_filename)
aws_commons.create_s3_uri('mybucket', s3_safe_filename,'us-east-1'),
```

If you have filenames with other unsafe characters, it would be good to use a more robust encoding system, like base64. In python, there is a module that provides both the functions in question: `base64.encode(string)` and `base64.decode(string)` .